# Call user defined functions from a For Loop in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am working on a WPF MVVM project and having a small requirement to add some function call in a list and call them in a loop.

Suppose having function declaration like this :

```
    public void GetReports(string[] arguments)
    {
        // My Code
    }

    public void GetUsers(string[] arguments)
    {
        // My Code
    }

    public void GetEmployess(string[] arguments)
    {
        // My Code
    }
```

and to call these functions I am currently using :

```
        GetReports(new string[] { "All" });

        GetUsers(new string[] { "All" });

        GetEmployess(new string[] { "All" });
```

Now I am having a requirement to call all these functions from a List or by using some other means so that I can get a count of no. of all the functions to process some time calculation dynamically.

I can't use this:

```
        List<string> ListFns = new List<string>();
        ListFns.Add("GetReports(new string[] { "All" });");
        ListFns.Add("GetReports(new string[] { "All" });");
        ListFns.Add("GetReports(new string[] { "All" });");
```

and then I could have iterated like this:

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= ListFns.Count() - 1; i++)
        {
        ListDataSets[i].ToString();
    }
```

This may not sound good but I have to do this in this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since all the methods have the same signature you can use a list of delegates:

```
var actions = new List<Action<string[]>>();
actions.Add(this.GetReports);
actions.Add(this.GetUsers);
actions.Add(this.GetEmployees);
```

And calling them is easy:

```
foreach (var action in actions)
{
    action(new[] { "All" });
}
```

If you want the parameters to be determined when the method call is scheduled (vs when it is actually performed) there are a number of options you can use. For example, packing the parameters into anonymous functions:

```
var actions = new List<Action>();
actions.Add(() => this.GetReports(new[] { "Foo" }));
actions.Add(() => this.GetUsers(new[] { "Bar" }));
// etc

foreach (var action in actions)
{
    action();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to know the no. of function call also like ListFns.Count(); any help on this?

Comment: If those methods are in a class named `SomeClass`, you can use `typeof(SomeClass).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name.StartsWith("Get"))`, then iterate over the enumerable this returns and execute those methods. This assumes no other methods start with "Get". See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx

Comment: @user2519971: I don't get it. A `List` has a `Count` property, what's the problem?

Comment: @user2519971 I just re-read your comment again. If you want to know the number of methods that start with "Get", you could use `typeof(SomeClass).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name.StartsWith("Get")).Count()`. Note that you cannot execute a string like a function, as you're trying to do in your code sample in your question.